# .local/share/autojump/autojump_errors: No such file or directory

Tags: bash

I've got autojump installed but, after upgrading homebrew, every time I issue a shell command (e.g. `ls`) I now get this:

```
-bash: /Users/snowcrash/.local/share/autojump/autojump_errors: No such file or directory
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: I've recently rewritten autojump in Go: github.com/suzaku/shonenjump/

Answer (score 1):

I believe this used to be an issue but according to this [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/wting/autojump/issues/63) it should be fixed.

Otherwise I recommend you quit your current terminal application and restart. It took that for mine to stop throwing the error after I upgraded.